# 'EXUpdates/EXUpdatesAppController.h' file not found XCODE

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to install my app into my iPhone, but i get this error while building. `'EXUpdates/EXUpdatesAppController.h' file not found`.

I've tried cleaning the project, but it had no success. What could it be? And how can it be fixed?

Comment: Jeroen did you get any solution? I am getting same issue in my project.